# go-git timing out creating tree

Tags: go, go-git, go-github

I'm doing a similar implementation of this example https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/03b5525554d33bcc1a735ab509224599107227a9/example/commitpr/main.go

I'm running into this error

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/XXX/XXX/git/trees: 502 Sorry, your request timed out.  It's likely that your input was too large to process.  Consider building the tree incrementally, or building the commits you need in a local clone of the repository and then pushing them to GitHub. []
```

The flow is as follows

- Check if the repo exists upstream if not create it
- Then loop through the file tree of a given folder path and add them to

```golang
func getTree(ref *github.Reference) (tree *github.Tree, err error) {
    // Create a tree with what to commit.
    entries := []*github.TreeEntry{}

    // Load each file into the tree.
    for _, fileArg := range buildFileTree() {
        file, content, err := getFileContent(fileArg)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        relativePath, _ := filepath.Rel(basePath, file)

        entries = append(entries, &github.TreeEntry{Path: github.String(relativePath), Type: github.String("blob"), Content: github.String(string(content)), Mode: github.String("100644")})
    }

    tree, _, err = client.Git.CreateTree(ctx, *sourceOwner.Login, *sourceRepo.Name, *ref.Object.SHA, entries)
    return tree, err
}
```

And this part is failing with the error stated above.
This folder is 35MB in size
Any idea on how to overcome this?
Would it make a difference to build the tree locally and then push it?

Comment: Hey did you get this fixed? I'm getting this same error and file size is not that big.

Comment: Sorry I haven't looked into this in a while but a potential solution is to build the tree locally with git or go-git and then use go-github to push it to github